# Bootstrap Datepicker taking value as one-day less than the selected date

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bootstrap-4, datepicker

I am using Bootstrap date-picker for capturing a certain date. But the selected date will become one-day less when its passed to backend.
The date I slected in UI -> 04-Apr-1997
The date shown in console -> 1997-04-03T18:30:00.000Z (as you can see...one day behind)

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
            <input id="OfficialDob" placeholder="Date of Birth" class="form-control" bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="bsConfig"
              formControlName="OfficialDob" />
          </div>
```

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
this.bsConfig = Object.assign(
      {},
      {
        containerClass: this.datepickerColorTheme,
        zIndexOffset: -3,
        dateInputFormat: 'DD-MMM-YYYY',
        showWeekNumbers: false
      }
    );
```

Why is it like this? Could anyone figure me how to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not an error. Datepicker takes input and sets date considering the timezone. While in console, it show the date in ISO format.
Use date.toLocaleDateString() and you will see the date you set.
Or consider adding timezone offset to the date if required.

Comment: Yeah..i used ISO string conversion intentionally.. Could you share some links reffering to time offset addition? Thanks

Comment: This will do it. `const newDate = new Date(oldDate.getTime()-new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*1000*60)`.Though i do not suggest to add timeZone offset.